# Why is cloth simulation not sewing on MB Lab character?

Tags: cloth-simulation

Trying out MB Labs modelling, and is experimenting with adding clothes.
Followed two tutorials on sewing clothes, but when starting simulation the clothing does not pull together at all? What am I missing out on?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the cloth object is a *Vertex Group* named "Sew" which is defined as *Pin Group* in the *Shape* settings of the cloth properties. When you delete it, the cloth starts pulling together. If you pin the vertices in place, the cloth simulation cannot pull them together. The result is far from perfect, but it starts sewing.

Apart from that, your normals are facing the wrong way and you should flip them, although this doesn't remove the gaps. There have been bug reports that cloth simulation produces gaps with self collision enabled where it worked better before, but anyway it depends on many factors to get a good sewing simulation.

Comment: Yup. I noticed this as well. But it doesn´t do the trick: it does not make a seam and sew it togetherl It leaves a gap. And from all tutorials I´ve seen you are supposed to pin group the seam-edges....

Comment: Well, no you don't have to add it as _Pin Group_. This was the reason it didn't start sewing and it has nothing to do with it being an MB Labs character. For all other problems on why it's not sewing better, you might want to check out the answer to this question: [Sewing clothes using a cloth modifier and a collision object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120752/sewing-clothes-using-a-cloth-modifier-and-a-collision-object)

Comment: PS: I guess you refer to older tutorials, in 2.7x versions you selected a vertex group for _Shrinking_ in the _Cloth Sewing Springs_ settings. This is obsolete, enabling the _Sewing_ option nowadays all edges without faces are considered sewing springs as the Blender manual states: "_Sewing springs are created by adding extra edges to a cloth mesh that are not included in any faces. They should connect vertices in the mesh that should be pulled together. For example the corners of a cloak._" Oh, and by the way: the normals of your cloth are facing the wrong way, you have to flip them.

Comment: @Hardashell I've edited my answer a little and added some information in the comments. As I said, older tutorials don't add the vertices to the _Pin Group_, but for the _Shrinking_. The vertex group itself is completely redundant for the sewing, it only helps if you want to select those vertices for whatever reason.